# How to get recent comments on pages that the user commented on in SQL or Ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, query-optimization

How do I get all the relevant comments for a user in an optimized manner? A *relevant comment* is a (recent) comment on a page that the user saved, and/or on a page that the user commented on. Below is my current code, but it's long and not optimal. How can I fix it, either with Ruby or SQL so it can return the comments quickly?

```
def self.relevant_comments(user)
    recent_comments = Comment.newest.first(50) #check through 50 most recent comments 
    saved_pages = user.saved_pages.to_set #get all of user's saved pages
    commented_pages =  Set.new
    user.comments.each {|comment| commented_pages.add comment.page } #get all the pages of user's comments

    #now go through the sets and put the relevant comments into `comments` 
    comments = Set.new
    recent_comments.each do |comment|
        page = comment.page
        comments.add(comment) if saved_pages.include?(page) or commented_pages.include?(page)
        break if comments.size >= 10
    end

    return comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pre-filtering the pages, like this:

```
def self.relevant_comments(user)
    recent_comments = Comment.newest.first(50) #check through 50 most recent comments 
    recent_page_ids = recent_comments.map(&:page_id)
    saved_pages = user.saved_pages.where(id: recent_page_ids).to_set #get all of user's saved pages
    commented_pages =  Set.new
    user.comments.where(page_id: recent_page_ids).each {|comment| commented_pages.add comment.page } #get all the pages of user's comments

    #now go through the sets and put the relevant comments into `comments` 
    comments = Set.new
    recent_comments.each do |comment|
        page = comment.page
        comments.add(comment) if saved_pages.include?(page) or commented_pages.include?(page)
        break if comments.size >= 10
    end

    return comments
end
```